# Timer_EntityBody IIS Error

Tags: iis, logging

I'm getting the Timer_EntityBody error in my HTTP error log. I'm familiar with what it means what I'm not familiar with is what does the preceding 4 mean in:

```
 - 4 Timer_EntityBody
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, that's a HTTPERR log.

Check out the 4th line from the top (the one that starts with `#Fields:`) - it'll tell you what the entries in the second column is.

My guess would be the Site ID